# Amplitude control in a signal generator

Tags: amplifier, feedback, function-generator

A am working on an FPGA based function generator and I am aiming for max frequency to be higher than 10 MHz, hopefully 30 MHz. I have implemented most of the functionality except amplitude control. Ideally I'd like to have a way to digitally control the amplitude. I have thought about using the following: digital attenuators, feedback amplifier circuits, some sort of FET used as variable resistor and not using any specific device at all and just changing the values I pass to the DAC.

**Changing the DAC values** seems the easiest however, it would negatively affect the resolution of the waveform on lower amplitudes.

Using a **feedback amp** seems to me like a good way to precisely control the amplitude  however the frequency response of many opamps and the whole circuit that would need to be designed makes for an uninviting option.

Similar stuff with using some sort of **FET**, say JFET. Something tells me that it wouldn't be as easy as sticking a resistor to a JFET and not expecting any degradation in signal fidelity.

I have no opinion on digital RF attenuators, I think that might be a way to go.

The question is if any of those approaches are better suited for operation at specified frequencies that the other, and what are the most frequently used approaches in the field?

Comment: Any idea how accurate you want to control the amplitude? +/-5%, 1%, 0.1%?

Comment: Not terribly important, say 5%. Signal integrity is much more important.

Comment: What's "signal integrity" if it does not include amplitude fidelity?

Comment: also, kind of contradictional: you care about the resolution at low levels, but you do not care about 5% amplitude mismatch.

Comment: I would use a set of attenuation 1/5/10/50 which can be done rather accurate. Then do the fine tuning using the ADC input signal.

Comment: I mean that if there's some inaccuracy in Vpp value of the whole waveform it doesn't matter as much. Amplitude fidelity with respect to neighbouring amplitudes i.e. signal integrity is important.

Comment: True, 5% may be too much. Although resolution on lower levels ties closely to distortion while amplitude mismatch does not as it seems to me. @Oldfart do you mean just resistive dividers or?

Comment: I have not thought about the details. The circuit should be such that the Ron of e.g. a  FET can be neglected against the resistors it switches. Maybe an Op-amp with feedback where the FETs switches a resistor to ground.

Comment: Use a Barry-Gilbert translinear analog multiplier. Enormous bandwidth, well past 30MHz.